# IBM Mobilefirst 8 error with the configure-tomcat-mysql.xml config file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I get the following error when I run the configure-tomcat-mysql.xml. This script is provided in the installation folder and I have made the necessary changes.

```
  BUILD FAILED
/home/madmin/software/ibm/configure-tomcat-mysql.xml:143: The element <applicationserver> inside <installmobilefirstadmin>, Tomcat version cannot be defined.
```

server details:

1.8.0_181

Linux Ubuntu 16.04

ant 1.9.6

tomcat 8

mysql:5.7.23

MFP V8

Thanks for your help

==UPDATE ---

I install tomcat 7 and had the same issue

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jun 27 2016 18:13:17 UTC
Server number:  7.0.68.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.15.0-1015-gcp
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13

[installmobilefirstadmin] [13/08/2018 16:01:16:631 UTC] Mon Aug 13 16:01:16 UTC 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connec
tion without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ req
uirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing
 applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly 
disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification
.
BUILD FAILED
/home/madmin/configure-tomcat-mysql.xml:143: The element <applicationserver> inside <installmobilefirstadmin>, Tom
cat version cannot be defined.
```

== Update 2 ===

I redo the entire install by downloading again the V8 zip file and the install manager but I get the same result

Can you let me know how to debug or resolve this issue

Comment: Can you try this with Tomcat 7.x? Just to see if there is a problem with the binary or the Tomcat version.

Comment: I tried tomcat 7 and see the same issue. Updated the question with the additional info